# Remove html table rows after 2nd row

Tags: jquery

how remove html table rows after 2nd row?
if in table have 5 row, 1 and 2 are safe, 3,4,5 must be remove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[detach(](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)**) instead of **[remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

```
var myremovedElems = $("#table tr:gt(1)").detach();
```

> The .detach() method is the same as
>   .remove(), except that .detach() 
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with
>   the removed elements. This method is
>   useful when removed elements are to be
>   reinserted into the DOM at a later
>   time.

Answer (score 4):

`$("#table tr:gt(1)").remove();`